# Soma de valores double incorreta!

Tags: c#, double

Num cliente a soma de 10 linhas em uma tabela deveria totalizar 100. O problema é que os valores informados totalizam 100 porém ao somar, mesmo que chumbando no código para evitar lixo vindo da aplicação a soma não fecha.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vejam que o erro está a mais de 10 casas decimais, sendo que trabalhei com no máximo 4. Gostaria de evitar um arredondamento visto que a soma simplesmente deveria dar certo.

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Estou curioso para saber a resposta. Isso também acontece no PHP, se eu informo em uma variavel o valor 16.8, dando um print aparece 16.79999

Comment: Um dos artigos mais famosos da computação se chama: "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic". A leitura do mesmo permite compreender a razão pra acontecer isso. O site http://floating-point-gui.de/, resume o artigo muito bem. Essa resposta merece ser bem elaborada e estou sem tempo pra isso no momento. Certamente alguns feras do SOpt como bigown, Luiz Vieira, entre outros já estão confeccionando uma bela resposta. :-)

Comment: Estranho, se você manda exibir o numero na tela pelo `Console.WriteLine(lValor)` ele mostra 100 certinho.

Comment: @MeuChapeu porque a hora que converte pra *string* pra imprimir tem um cálculo, que neste caso acabou por arredondar do jeito esperado mas é pura coincidência, nada garante que será sempre assim. --- Eu fechei por duplicata, porque já tem a explicação do porque há este erro para todas linguagens. Não tem porque ficar duplicando perguntas que no fundo a resposta, não use `double` quando precisa de exatidão e seja feliz.

Comment: Como o @cantoni citou, existe uma explicação e a ideia é que double e float não são exatamente precisos. A solução para o meu caso foi instanciar o valor como decimal ao invés de double.